# how to select content of field after setting its value?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have simple form (JSF, ManagedBean) with two input fields
"from" and "to". When user fills in "from" and moves with TAB
to "to" field I want to have value from "from" to be copied to
"to" and then select that content of "to" so the user can
overwrite it, if he decides to do so.

thank you for your help
Dalibor

Comment: are you using PrimeFaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using a event `keyup`:

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="From: "/>
    <h:inputText id="from" value="#{bean.from}" >
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="to" execute="@this" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="To: "/>
    <h:inputText id="to" value="#{bean.to}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

In the `<f:ajax>` the event attribute is a HTML events whithout the on prefix, can also be valueChange and action, in the example we make the ajax request in the onkeyup event.

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {
    private String from;
    private String to;

    public String getFrom() { return from;}

    public void setFrom(String from) { this.from = from;}

    public String getTo() { return to; }

    public void setTo(String to) { this.to = to; }    
}
```

For selecting text when the input focussed, use something like

```
<p:inputText onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)"/>
```